# SSL Certificate Error with python-arango Library

Tags: kubernetes, arangodb, python-arango

I am trying to connect the Python-Arango [library](https://github.com/joowani/python-arango) to an application. I have set up the ArangoDB on Kubernetes nodes using this [tutorial](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/tutorials-kubernetes.html). My yaml file for the cluster is like this:

```
---
apiVersion: "database.arangodb.com/v1alpha"
kind: "ArangoDeployment"
metadata:


name: "arango-cluster"
spec:
  mode: Cluster
  image: arangodb/arangodb:3.7.6
  tls:
    caSecretName: arango-cluster-ca
  agents:
    storageClassName: my-local-storage
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 2Gi
  dbservers:
    storageClassName: my-local-storage
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 17Gi
  externalAccess:
    type: NodePort
    nodePort: 31200
```

Setup seems fine, since I am able to access the web UI as well as through Arango shell. However, when I am using the python-arango library to connect my application to the DB, I am getting a certificate related error:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /_db/testDB/_api/document/demo/10010605 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

When doing `kubectl get secrets`, I see `arango-cluster-ca` there, which I have explicitly mentioned in the YAML file above. I have also set the verification flag in the python code False as follows

```
db = client.db(name='testDB', verify=False, username='root', password='')
```

Yet, it does not bypass the verification as expected.

I would like to understand what I could have missed - either during setup, or in the Python call - which is not letting me bypass this SSL certificate error issue, or if it's possible to set the certificate up. I tried this Arango [tutorial](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/deployment-kubernetes-tls.html) to setup a certificate, but it did not give me success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I was able to figure out was to opt for the unsecured route.
Instead of having `arango-cluster-ca` in the `spec.tls.caSecretName` field of arango cluster config file, I set the field to `None`. It allowed me to connect with http without any issues.

Would still like to know if there is some workaround to get it connected via https, so I am still open to answers, else I would close this.

Answer (score 0):

just found a workaround using some [undocumented switches](https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/python-arango/blob/8e35379254a6efe6c5528fc05e117b1d2e928d87/arango/client.py#L176):

```py
    arango_client = ArangoClient(hosts=ARANGO_DB_URL, verify_override=False)
    arango_db = arango_client.db(ARANGO_DB_NAME, username=ARANGO_DB_USER, password=ARANGO_DB_PASSWORD, verify_certificate=False)
```